# Does Raphael js uses canvas or svg?

Tags: canvas, svg, raphael

As seen on the [Home page](http://raphaeljs.com/) of Raphael Js it says:

> Raphaël is a small JavaScript library that should simplify your work
>   with vector graphics on the web.
>
> Raphaë uses the SVG W3C Recommendation and VML as a base for creating
>   graphics.

But when it comes to creating Raphael objects such as in this [LINK](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael):

it says:

> Creates a canvas object on which to draw. You must do this first, as
>   all future calls to drawing methods from this instance will be bound
>   to this canvas

I am confused whether it uses canvas or svg because canvas uses raster type format which pixels out when scaled when compared to SVG which uses paths to draw and remember shapes as scene graph or Document Object Model.

Comment: I think that what they do call canvas is the SVG Element on which it will draw after. Maybe not the best word, because of this possible confusion,  but it actually says [what it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raphael uses an SVG element, it doesn't use Canvas (at all, anywhere). It could use VML for older browser support.

Its just sometimes the variable names people use for the main Raphael element are things like paper or canvas (and Raphael calls its paper a canvas, which is confusing), as it describes it well.

If we look at what is underlying the Raphael object itself, we can take a peek (I assume on a very old IE it may look a bit different and be VML)..

```
var paper = new Raphael('mydiv', 100, 100);
console.log( paper.canvas );
```

displays

```
<svg height="100" version="1.1" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">

  <desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Raphaël 2.1.0</desc>  
  <defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">

  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: So what rendered as out put will be SVG right? Or Raphael is using canvas as a layer as drawing surface?

Comment: Yes, it will be pure SVG (or VML), there is no HTML5 canvas at all involved, and that should be wiped from memory :).

Comment: Any links to support it will be very useful for me at work